# Passive monitor speakers with reference amplifier, how do I add a subwoofer?

Tags: speakers

I see Behringer makes a two channel reference amplifier the A500. This amplifier is well regarded at the price point. They also make the 2030p (passive) reference monitors: these speakers have *excellent* reviews. There is one caveat with the speakers though -- they need a woofer.

How would I hook up a woofer using a reference amp and passive speakers?

Would that requires a crossover before the amp, and another amp for the woofer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a crossover before or after the amp - the only downside to placing it after the amp is that the amp needs to be able to drive the woofer as well as the existing monitors - requiring more power, and possibly reducing clarity.

In this scenario I would probably run the crossover before the amp, and add a dedicated amp for the woofer. This way you can spec this second amp for your preferred response at low frequencies.